# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, windows, directory, runtime-error

I get this error when I run my code. Essentially it should be moving data from whichever string matches mapping to the string in textbox1.

The entire error is as follows:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\jpearson\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug\0110'.

I have validated that all of the file paths in the code are valid, so I am not entirely sure what I am missing.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }


        private Dictionary<string, string> mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
         {
             { "0110", @"C:/Example" },
             { "1000", @"C:/Example2" },
             { "1100", @"C:/Example3" },
         };

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string destination = textBox1.Text;
    string source = textBox2.Text;

    if (mapping.ContainsKey(source))
    {
        foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(source))
        {
            File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(f)));
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Oh No! Something went wrong, try again!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain a little more about your file organization and what the expected behavior is? It's hard to divine this information from your code. For example, I see you have a dictionary yet you only ever look at the key. Also the key is showing up in the path of the error message. How is the key related to the path?

Comment: maybe you would like to Directory.GetFiles(mappings[source]) !?

Comment: Essentially what happens is the program has comboboxes that generate answers in a linear fashion. If i answer 1 in combobox1 I get a list of answers in combobox2 two that are different than if I had chosen 2. Once I have chosen all of the comboboxes a code is generated in textbox2 from the combined selected indexes of the comboboxes. As for textbox1, we simply use the FolderBrowserDialog to select the destination value.  Therefore string mapping = the source and destination derrives from textbox1. does that make more sense? (I'm an ubernoob so i apologize if none of this makes sense)

Answer (score 2):

From code and example that you supplied I would say that key is value that you supplied through GUI and that key is mapped to folder that is value in dictionary. I would say that you forgot to get value for given key and that you are searching for folder with your key name '0110' for example. So I would suggest you to change code something like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string destination = textBox1.Text;
    string source = textBox2.Text;

    if (mapping.ContainsKey(source))
    {
        string directoryName = mapping[source];
        foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName))
        {
            File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(f)));
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Oh No! Something went wrong, try again!");
    }
}
```

This is my assumption.

Hope that I helped you :)